# Php Function Restricted area

Tags: php, html, mysql, function

Hey i have this function :

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['login']) && $_POST['login'] == 'LOGARE') {

        include('./inc/configurare.php');
            mysql_select_db('account');

        $user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
        $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);

            $check = "SELECT * from account where login = '" . $user . "' and password = PASSWORD('$pass')";
                $query = mysql_query($check);
                    $num = mysql_num_rows($query);


            if($num > 0) {

                $array = mysql_fetch_array($query);


            // SESSION variable start //

            $_SESSION['id'] = $array['login'];
            $_SESSION['coins'] = $array['coins'];
            $_SESSION['isadmin'] = $array['isadmin'];
            $_SESSION['pscadmin'] = $array['pscadmin'];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $array['email'];
            $_SESSION['real_name'] = $array['real_name'];
            $_SESSION['social_id'] = $array['social_id'];
            $_SESSION['user_admin'] = $array['web_admin']; 
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $array['id'];
            $_SESSION['user_name'] = $array['login'];
            $_SESSION['user_coins'] = $array['coins'];
            $_SESSION['user_email'] = $array['email'];
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL=index.php?s=home'>";
            } else {
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL=index.php?s=login_error'>";
            }
        }

?>
```

And i wanna restrict acces on some page , you must login to intro in that page somting like this:

```
<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && isset($_SESSION['pass']))

{

    auto_unban();

    $username = $_SESSION['user'];

    $sql = mysql_query("Select * from account.account where login='".$_SESSION['user']."'") or die(mysql_error());

    $accc=mysql_fetch_object($sql);

    $charss = mysql_query("Select * from player.player where account_id='".$accc->id."'") or die(mysql_error());

    $chars = mysql_num_rows($charss);

?>

<script type='text/javascript'>

function myFunction()

{

var jmsg = "<? echo "Blocked : ".$acc->unban_date." pentru ".$acc->motiv_ban.".mlock."; ?>";

    if(jmsg){

        alert(jmsg);

    }

    window.onload=myFunction;

}

</script>

Script , script

<?php } else { echo "Please login!";} ?>
```

That script when i don't login show me this echo : Please login! 
and when i'm login also show me that `echo` : Plase login!

I don't know how to create and read function in php can anyone show me how to make function like this :

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && isset($_SESSION['pass']))
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php

Answer (score 0):

Your variable $_SESSION['login'] is empty because you forgot to call session_start(); at the beginning of your php script.

Place session_start(); before printing any chars on your page.
ex:

```
<?php session_start(); 
$_SESSION['login'] =  'login';
...
```